# Fusionar Cambios repositorios gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

Tengo 2 repositorios, el repositorio A que contiene un proyecto js de ventas, mientras que el repositorio B contiene el mismo proyecto solo que este se encuentra migrado, necesito agregar en el repositorio B todos los cambios que se han realizado en el repositorio A, ya que el repositorio B tiene alrededor de 4 meses de atrasos en actualizaciones versus el repositorio A, como podría hacer esto? ambos repositorios estan subidos en gitlab

Comment: que quieres decir con "migrado"? El repositorio B es un clon/fork del repositorio A? Comparten historia (es decir, revisiones en su historia)?

Comment: El repositorio B es una copia del repositorio A

Comment: ya que no usaste la palabra fork/clone, entonces **asumo** que alguien tomó el _contenido_ del proyecto del repositorio A y lo arrancó como un proyecto nuevo _sin historia_ en el proyecto B.

Answer (score 1):

Si el proyecto del repositorio A fue copiado al repositorio B para **arrancar** un nuevo proyecto sin historia, entonces el proceso es un poco fastidioso, pero posible.... asumiendo que el layout del contenido de la rama del repositorio B es como la del repositorio A (mismos archivos en las mismas rutas).

Primero, tienes que tener un repositorio que tenga visión de ambos repositorios en gitlab como remotos. Digamos que el repositorio A es el remoto `repoA` y el repositorio B es el remoto `repoB`.

```
git fetch repoA
git fetch repoB
```

Tienes que identificar la revisión en el repositorio A que corresponde a la **revisión raiz** del repositorio B. Una vez que la tengas identificada, creemos una rama en la revisión del repositorio A para que nos sea fácil manejarla:

```
git branch raizDeB el-id-de-la-revision-en-repoA # raizDeB es el nombre de la rama
```

Una vez que tienes hecho eso, entonces se trata de traerte todos los cambios desde raizDeB hasta la punta de la rama que estás manejando en repoA:

```
git rebase --onto repoB/main raizDeB repoA/main
```

En ese ejemplo usé main de ambos repos, pero puede ser cualquier rama.

Estoy trabajando en `detached HEAD` porque las operaciones se están haciendo sobre ramas remotas..... luego de terminar vas a tener que empujar lo que tienes en `HEAD` a alguna rama del `repoB` pero eso ya es un detalle adicional que no tiene que ver con el hecho de traer los cambios.

Como comentario adicional: la idea de arrancar un nuevo repositorio con solo el contenido del repositio A (sin clonarlo) no es buena... precisamente porque te toca hacer trabajo adicional (como este que estamos haciendo) para traer los cambios del repositorio A al repositorio B. Dependiendo de la complejidad de las ramas del repositorio B, podrían considerar *mudar* el trabajo que han hecho en el B sobre un clon del A, pero esa es una pregunta totalmente diferente.